# Disabling Caching in Peewee

Tags: python, peewee

The documentation says that peewee caches the data while select operation.
Is there any way to disable the caching while executing select query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iterator()` method of the `QueryResultWrapper` object returned by calls to `.select()` when iterating over a large number of rows to avoid the results being cached in memory.

From the [peewee documentation on Iterating over large result sets](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#iterating-over-large-result-sets):

> To reduce the amount of memory used by peewee when iterating over a
> query, use the iterator() method. This method allows you to iterate
> without caching each model returned, using much less memory when
> iterating over large result sets.
>
> ```py
> # Let's assume we've got 10 million stat objects to dump to a csv file.
> stats = Stat.select()
>
> # Our imaginary serializer class
> serializer = CSVSerializer()
>
> # Loop over all the stats and serialize.
> for stat in stats.iterator():
>     serializer.serialize_object(stat)
> ```